# Format number to 2 decimal places only if it has decimal places

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want d3 to format my number to 2 decimal places, only if it has decimal value.
Also, I want it to work with one single format function.

For now, I have been using this. Is there any way I can improve this to be able to work around?

```
d3.format(",.2f")(10101); //10,101.00 which must be displayed as 10,000 only

d3.format(",.2f")(12334.2); //12,334.20 this is okay
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want it to work with one single format function

Well, that's not possible. D3 format functions cannot *adapt*  to the number you pass to them like that.

However, you can have **two** format functions, and test to see if the number you're passing has or has not decimal places. This is one possible way to test:

```
number % 1
```

Which returns 0 for integers.

Then, in a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you can choose which `d3.format` function you'll use:

```
!(number % 1) ? someFormat(number) : otherFormat(number)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var formatInteger = d3.format(",");
var formatDecimal = d3.format(",.2f");

var number1 = 10101;
var number2 = 12334.2;

function format(number){
return !(number % 1) ? formatInteger(number) : formatDecimal(number)
}

console.log(format(number1))
console.log(format(number2))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

The closest you can get to that is if you use the '~' to remove any trailing zeroes. So in your case, the format would ',.2~f'.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(d3.format(",.2~f")(10101));
console.log(d3.format(",.2~f")(12334.2));
</script>
```

More info about d3-format here: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-format

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const formattedValue = value >= 100000
                ? value % 1 === 0
                  ? SI(value).replace(".0", "")
                  : SI(value)
                : value
```